# Bootstrap Carousal disappears when clicking on a slide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When leaving the slides automatically play there's no problem, but when i click on an individual slide everything disappears.

```
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide-to=#{index} <%= index == 0 ? 'class="active"' : '' %>></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <div class="item <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
    <%= image_tag image , size: 200 %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>


  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: do you have any error in console ?

Comment: no errors showing on console